# Do a Command After an Action Has Been Completed - SpriteKit

Tags: if-statement, sprite-kit, skaction

In SpriteKit, I have a simple action for my sprite:

```
sprite.size = CGSizeMake(40, 10);
sprite.physicsBody =[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.size];
sprite.position = CGPointMake(65, 230);
SKAction *changeImage = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"raniSlide"]];
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:.1];
SKAction *changeImage2 = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"raniStick"]];
SKAction *sequence=[SKAction sequence:@[changeImage, wait, changeImage2]];
[sprite runAction:sequence];
```

It changes textures, waits, then changes textures again. This is so it ducks for a certain time period. After ducking I want it to change back to its original size. When I put the code for changing size after the runAction command, it doesn't perform the first sprite.size = CGSizeMake(40, 10), and doesn't duck at all, as it stays the same size as it was in the beginning. So I was wondering how to make an if statement that when if an action has been completed, it then changes the size of the sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with an `if` statement, but take a look at [`runAction:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction:completion:). You use it like:

```
[sprite runAction:sequence completion:^{
    // the action is complete, change size back
}];
```